# Cannot see the subscriptions with global administrator access in Azure AD

Tags: azure, subscription, administration

I have the global admin account in my organization's Windows Azure AD and need to manage the subscriptions of my organization in Azure. I see No subscriptions error message when logging on management portal manage.windowsazure.com. I guess I need to be a co-administrator of the organization subscription. I think that global administrator rights should be enough to give the co-administrator rights to my own account. The question is How can I get the co-administrator rights to the azure subscription if I have global administrator rights in Azure AD?

Comment: Do you have an enterprise subscription (portal access) with Microsoft?  If so, use the Enterprise Portal.

Comment: This is not an enterprise subscription. At least my organizational account is not valid on the enterprise portal. Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: If you are an admin of the Azure subscription, you should be able to see the subscriptions you are admin of (I admin multiple enterprise, MSDN and personal Azure accounts in a single log in).  If you have a enterprise/org account the account is going to be under your org's domain account.  Previous Azure subs required a "Live" account.  I had to make myself co-admin of the other account to have everything under one umbrella.  Are you sure you are logging in with the correct account?  Azure support for billing and security is FREE (not technical), so contact them and they are pretty responsive.

Answer (score 2):

No, all what you need is to set the "Access management for Azure resources" option on your AzureAD Tenant. This way you will get access to all subscriptions. Please keep in mind this option is like a "Break Glass" or Emergency option. I would not recommend having it enableded all the time. You can however enable it, get access to what you need (e.g. set yourself as owner on 1 or more subscriptions) and then disable it back.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin.md#azure-portal